# What specification on cables do I need for them to power from USB-C to USB male A?

Tags: usb

The cooling pad I have came with a USB male A to male A cable to power it up. I lost the cable and wanted to use either the USB type c or thunderbolt port on my Alienware laptop to power it up(as I don't have enough USB A female ports).

The two USB male to USB C cables that I tried, which I use to charge my phone don't work. I guess the power cable delivered 1 way only on those 2 cable from USB male A to USB-C

What specification on cables do I need for them to power from USB-C to USB male A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a "cooling pad" with Type-A receptacle, you are in a bit of inconvenience. USB Type-A ports are designated for USB hosts, and the use of Type-A  on a peripheral device is illegal from specification point of view, and that's why you have trouble to feed your pad with standard legacy Aplug->C cable.

The Type-A(plug)->C cables are designed/specified to deliver legacy power from A to C, meaning that the C-end looks like a "host" to Type-C receptacle in your laptop. This means that your laptop won't engage power on VBUS, and will act as a device. To look like a USB host, the Type-C end of the c**able has a pull-up** 56k resistor on one of CC lines inside the cable overmold.

To get VBUS out of your laptop, the Type-C end of cable must "look" as USB device, and thus must have **5.1k pull-down** on a CC pin, again inside the overmold. There exist so-called "Type-C OTG adapters", which have this pull-down built in, but they have a Type-A **receptacle** on the other end of cable. So the "OTG adapter" converts a Type-C port into a regular Type-A host port. And we came back to having a nonstandard A-A cable to solve your problem.

CONCLUSION: to feed a non-standard cooler (equipped with custom Type-A **receptacle**), you will need to make your own custom cable. You should get a "Type-C OTG cable"

[image]

and either find a replacement for your A-A cable, or take a standard A-B cable, cut the B-end short, cut the "Type-C OTG cable, splice wires, and connect black-to-black and red-to-red wires ignoring the rest of wires. It won't be pretty, but it will work.

ADDITION: There are Type-c OTG adapters of "nano" type, like this one

[image]

These adapters are plugged right inside the Type-A plug. But you still have to have the A-A cable to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Throw it away.  Any device that used USB-A to USB-A for power violates the USB standard and is a fire hazard.  There is no standard for these cables that allows for power to pass safely.  Loosing the cable was a good thing, it's an excuse to dispose of the device it used.  The only problem is that with the cable lost someone else might find it and use it improperly and start something on fire.  Trying to convince a USB-C to USB-A cable to provide power will only make things worse.  Instead of playing with 12 watts of power you could be dealing with 27 watts, 45 watts, 60 watts, or potentially 100 watts.

If you want to play with fire then do it far away from me.